# Creating a Process object whose function is from another Class [Causes Error]

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, multiprocessing, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I'll explain my question **as best as I can** and please **I really need your help** especially to people who are an expert in Python Multiprocessing cause I love Multiprocessing & I'm just a beginner learning.

```
def __handleDoubleClick(self,item):

        self.tmx_window.show()

        processes = []

        #self.tmx_window.fill_table(item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text())
        process_ft = Process(target=self.tmx_window.fill_table, args=(item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text()))
        processes.append(process_ft)
        process_ft.start()


        for process in processes:
            process.join()
```

Now I have here a function (`__handleDoubleClick`) & this function simply does something when you double click a widget from my PYQT5 GUI, as you can see this line of code right here `self.tmx_window.show()` this shows up the **2nd** GUI that I have. If you are curious about the `self.tmx_window` object this is its class and it simply inherits a class `QMainWindow` & `Ui_TmxWindow` the `Ui_TmxWindow` comes from the generated `.py` file from **QT Designer**.

```
class TmxWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_TmxWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.setupUi(self)
```

As you can also see again I have here a function that is called which is this code.

```
#self.tmx_window.fill_table(item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text())
```

Now I have commented it out and I wanted to make it a Process object cause I want to apply **multiprocessing** and I need it to run along side with other process in the future... Now as you can see I have applied this

```
process_ft = Process(target=self.tmx_window.fill_table, args=(item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text()))
processes.append(process_ft)
process_ft.start()


for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

The **value** of target there is a function which is this `self.tmx_window.fill_table` and that function as you can see is from another class which I created an object from and that object as you can see is `self.tmx_window`. Now without applying multi-processing everything works fine cause I do the function calling right... but when I apply the multiprocessing this error comes up. By the way you'll see there **"TmxWindow object"** from the error and `TmxWindow` is the class I am referring to where the function belongs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 127, in __handleDoubleClick
    process_ft.start()
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'TmxWindow' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\.conda\envs\USA24\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Now I have thought of trying to do the same thing but with **Threading** and I tried this instead of **Process** and IT WORKED! I am familiar about the difference of threads and processes and based on what I've read that threads share on memory while processes don't cause they have their own (correct me if I'm wrong) so that's why I wanted to apply multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

So the question is I am worried about is the error I've provided... and why does it work with Threading tho and not with Process  . I feel like there's something that I do not understand yet a lot of MultiProcessing and I am just curious I mean I just followed it and provided a function to the Process object and that function comes from a different class which I created an instance of an object with... So can someone help me... Pleaaaseee. Thank you!

```
#self.tmx_window.fill_table(item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text())
thread_ft = threading.Thread(target=self.tmx_window.fill_table,args=[item.text(),self.language_code,self.xml_filepath.text()])
threads.append(thread_ft)
thread_ft.start()
```

Comment: What `self.tmx_window.fill_table()` does? Does it access an item view, possibly a QTableView or QTableWidget, to create/edit its items?

Comment: Yes it does some adding of rows from the QTableWidget `self.tmx_table.setRowCount(4)`  and I also have another function after that but it just processes some data and outputs a .csv file

Comment: For now it's only 4 rows but soon I'll be adding more depending on a specific `len()` of a list so yeep... I'm so curious why it gets that error :( and the `Threading` works tho

Comment: For future reference, a small suggestion: please avoid unnecessary "chat" slang ("so let's get to the point", smileys, "pleeeeasee", lots of ellipsis, etc). As the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (which you should've taken) reports: «This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.». While kindness is obviously more than welcome (in behavior, mostly), anything else is usually considered noise, especially for people using search engines to look for answers, as they're usually interested in *direct* answers, not greetings or funny faces.

Comment: Okaaay okaay you're right! thaanks got it!

Answer (score 0):

The important aspect to consider is that **no** access to GUI elements (including creating new ones) is allowed from any external *thread* besides the main Qt thread.

When using multiprocessing, each process has its own threads (I'm simplifying a lot, be aware), so if you're using multiprocessing you're basically also using different threads. Also, communication between processing in python is done by pickling (which doesn't work very well with Qt objects).

While in some circumstances accessing UI elements from other threads *might* work, it's usually just by coincidence, as the current hw/sw configuration allows those threads to work synchronously, since they are probably very responsive and their communication queue isn't troubled by other events. But, again, that's mostly a *coincidence*. I'm pretty sure that under other conditions (slow CPU, other concurring processes, etc.) your code won't work even when using threading.

So, the **only** safe solution *is* to use threading, but only along with Qt's signals and slot as long as you need to access **in any way** with UI elements. Which means that you have to use a QThread subclass (since it inherits from QObject, it provides the signal/slot mechanism), do your "processing" there and communicate with the main Qt thread with your custom signals, which will be therefore connected to the function that actually updates your item view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... So multiprocessing is off the charts and I guess I should be using threading then... may I ask on what do you mean by  **but only along with Qt's signals and slot**

Comment: You need to create what's usually called a "Worker" thread, which is a custom subclass of QThread. In that subclass you create your own custom signal(s) according to your needs, then create a `run()` method that will do all the processing; when that processing has finished emit the signal that is going to communicate with the main thread what's "changed". You obviously need to connect that signal(s) to the appropriate function prior to call `start()` on that object to actually start it. Look for "QThread" and "worker" related Q&A, you'll find lots of results even here on StackOverflow.